# Xcode 15 crashing Symbol not found

Tags: xcode

> dyld[75009]: Symbol not found: _$sSo15NSAppKitVersionaSL03AppB0Mc
> Referenced from:  /Users/johanneswerner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NordVPN-dixqimdogseddtbnnsxivwtxsogk/Build/Products/Debug/NordVPN.app/Contents/MacOS/NordVPN
> Expected in:     <55F7D958-6ED1-3C36-A70E-94D7FFC18D5A> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit

Xcode 14 works fine.

We are using a mixer of cocoapods and SPM for dependency management.

Comment: @NuzhdinVladimir I added the solution here stackoverflow.com/a/77818649/1898829

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for this was to link AppKit library in Link Binaries with Libaries in the target Build Phase and say Optional. [image]